# SBT 0.13.8 multi module project with Playframework 2.4.2

Tags: scala, sbt, multi-module, playframework-2.4

I have a simple project with two submodules, proja and projb. Proja contains trait UserController used in UserControllerImpl inside projb.

project on github: https://github.com/aswarcewicz/play-sbt-multimodule

root build.sbt:

```
name := """proj"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val proja = Project(id = "proj-a", base = file("modules/proj-a"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val projb = Project(id = "proj-b", base = file("modules/proj-b"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(proja)
  .aggregate(proja)

lazy val root = Project(id = "proj", base = file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(proja, projb)
  .aggregate(proja, projb)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

and error from compiler:

> modules/proj-b/app/controllers/UserControllerImpl.scala:5: not found:
>   object controller [error] import controller._
>
> /modules/proj-b/app/controllers/UserControllerImpl.scala:10: not
>   found: type UserController [error] class UserControllerImpl extends
>   Controller with UserController {

I have no idea what can be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors.

I will commit the changes that your project needs to work in following repository.
https://github.com/martinscmb/play-sbt-multimodule

```
localhost:9000/test output:
{"user":{"name":"toto","age":25,"email":"toto@jmail.com","isAlive":true,"friend":{"name":"tata","age":20,"email":"tata@coldmail.com"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your SBT file to:

```
name := """proj"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = Project(id = "proj", base = file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .aggregate(proja, projb)

lazy val proja = Project(id = "proj-a", base = file("modules/proj-a"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)

lazy val projb = Project(id = "proj-b", base = file("modules/proj-b"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(proja)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

Add correct dependencies and reload your project.

Comment: Did you try it on project from github? Because it doesn't work.

Comment: Your SBT file was syntactically wrong, now you can add the dependency you want

Comment: and you don't need a sbt file per project anymore

Answer (score 0):

You want to define a commonSettings module and pass through everywhere:

```
import sbt.Keys._

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.7",
  routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator,
  version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
    .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
    .settings(commonSettings)
    .settings(Seq(name := """proj"""))
    .dependsOn(`proj-a`, `proj-b`)
    .aggregate(`proj-a`, `proj-b`)

lazy val `proj-b` = (project in file("modules/proj-b"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .dependsOn(`proj-a`).aggregate(`proj-a`)

lazy val `proj-a` = (project in file("modules/proj-a"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala)
  .settings(commonSettings)
```